# VS 2013 to 2015 "Post-build event command line" error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, post-build-event

I am moving a project from VS 2013 to VS 2015 and when I go to compile a project I get "The command "call “C:***\vcvarsall.bat” x86
“C:***\EditBin.exe” “E:***.exe”  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE" exited with code 123.

If I go into (r-click project) properties->BuildEvents "Post-Build event command line" and delete

call “$(DevEnvDir)....\vc\vcvarsall.bat” x86
“$(DevEnvDir)....\vc\bin\EditBin.exe” “$(TargetPath)”  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE

It compiles and starts fine.  Do I need the post-build command?  If so can someone help me with the error.

Comment: Looks familiar, brr, the awful things that happen to my code.  Replace the “curly quotes” that a word processor would generate with "straight quotes".  Couple of spares to copy paste: """""""""""""

Comment: Not sure I understand your suggestion.  I put quotes around the command only in this post (removed now).  I did make sure the quotes were correct in the text field, and got the same error.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant ! I have this damn issue too.